# Refresh/reset link/WResource of WPushButton after click but before redirection

Tags: wt

Is there a way to reset the link of a WPushButton after it's clicked but before the browser is directed to the link or resource?

Background is that I have a WResource which copys an item/tablemodel (derived from WAbstractTableModel), to freeze it's state/data and do a csv file conversion based on it. So when my "download current state as csv" button is clicked, I need to create a new WResource and set the buttons link to it, before the whole redirection mechanism is triggered. How can I achieve that?

**Edit**: Looks like this is not achievable with Wt at the moment, see [my this post in the official Wt forum](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/11439?r=11467)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a resource which takes a model on its creation and then extracts data from it inside `handleRequest` method.

An example:

```
class TableResource : public WResource
{
public:
    TableResource(WStandardItemModel *model, WObject *parent) :
        WResource(parent),
        model(model)
    {

    }

    ~TableResource()
    {
        beingDeleted();
    }

    void handleRequest(const Http::Request &request, Http::Response &response)
    {
        std::string data;

        for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i)
        {
            std::string row;

            for (int j = 0; j < model->columnCount(); ++j)
            {
                row.append(model->item(i, j)->text().toUTF8());
                row.append(";");
            }

            data.append(row);
            data.append("\n");
        }

        response.setMimeType("text/plain");
        response.out() << data;
    }

private:
    WStandardItemModel *model;
};
```

Usage:

```
WApplication* createApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env)
{
    WApplication *app = new WApplication(env);

    WStandardItemModel *model = new WStandardItemModel(app);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<WStandardItem*> items;

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            WStandardItem *item = new WStandardItem;
            item->setText(WString("item {1} {2}").arg(i).arg(j));
            items.push_back(item);
        }

        model->appendRow(items);
    }

    WTableView *table = new WTableView(app->root());
    table->setModel(model);

    WPushButton *btn = new WPushButton(app->root());
    btn->setText("export");
    btn->setResource(new TableResource(model, btn));

    return app;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the try but you overlooked the essential problem I described in my question: "I have a WResource which copys an item/tablemodel ... to freeze it's state/data". This is because the user can change the model, even between subsequent `handleRequest` calls, due the concurrent nature of `Wt::WRessource`. 
I workaround the problem at the moment with 2 button calls, see http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/11439?r=11467#message-11467